# ObjectDisposedException SslStream and TcpClient

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am using a TcpClient with an SslStream.  In general everything works fine but we are getting occasional logs of crashes.  It seems to be coming from unstable network connections, and I'm unfortunately not able to reproduce it locally despite  trying to create "unexpected circumstances":

- using Fiddler to replicate a very slow network connection
- killing the server application while its sending data
- disconnecting network cables

The situation is this:

I call BeginRead like this:

```
_tcpClientStream.BeginRead(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length, pfnCallBack, null);
```

And then EndRead is being called like this:

```
iRx = _tcpClientStream.EndRead(asyn);
```

The only place that the iRx is used is to copy the received data to a new array:

```
var bytes = new byte[iRx];
Array.Copy(receiveBuffer, bytes, iRx);
```

In the OnDataReceived callback function, I call EndRead on the SslStream, which throws an exception that is handled:

```
Error in OnDataReceived System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: size
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.StartReading()
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at XXXXXXX.OnDataRecevied(IAsyncResult asyn)
```

Normally this is not a problem - this exception is caught and the TcpClient is closed and re-initiated to attempt to reconnect.

However, in this case there is a second Exception that is thrown and comes from one of the UnhandledException error handlers:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
Current.DispatcherUnhandledException
Current.Dispatcher.UnhandledException
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException
```

This stack trace is like this:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Our handling for this type of unhandled error is to display a message to the user that there is a fatal error and the software has to close.

My questions are:

1. Has anyone ever seen this error before and been able to reproduce the exact out of range exception I'm getting?  Despite my attempts to recreate the issue (using the methods described above), I'm not able to ever recreate the exception, it is always the more standard Socket IO exception:

   ```
   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
      at System.Net.Security._SslStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
      at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
      at XXXXXXXXX.OnDataRecevied(IAsyncResult asyn)
   ```
2. Is there any way I can handle this exception in my Socket code or is it always going to appear in one of these UnhandledException events?  If so, what is the best practice way of handling this?  Basically I need some logic in the event handler to identify that the software should not shut down if this specific error is received?

Comment: Nothing unusual, just bugs in your code.  Exceptions are your friend, they tell you when your code is wrong.  The 1st exception tells you that you always need to pass the size of the byte[] buffer and not how many bytes are still available.  The 2nd exception is entirely normal, you closed the socket while there was a pending BeginRead.  You need to catch the ODE and stop calling BeginRead.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for the reply.  I added some information in response to your comment about the first exception.  The code is always using the length of the receive buffer - I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious here...  For the second point - makes sense.  I only started using the SslStream recently, but from what I understand it is not me that is calling the BeginRead on the underlying NetworkStream.  I call EndRead on SslStream, which then seems to internally call BeginRead on the underlying NetworkStream.  This is the situation I don't fully understand.